# I use Windows 10 and I'm failing to download Visual Studio Code on my WSL 2

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I open Ubuntu in a PowerShell or Windows terminal and type "code", it just says updating and then failed:

```
code
```

Output:

```
Updating VS Code Server to version a6606b6ca720bca780c2d3c9d4cc3966ff2eca12
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (a6606b6ca720bca780c2d3c9d4cc3966ff2eca12)
Downloading: 100%
Failed
--2024-03-08 14:30:17--  https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:a6606b6ca720bca780c2d3c9d4cc3966ff2eca12/server-linux-x64/stable
Resolving update.code.visualstudio.com (update.code.visualstudio.com)... 13.107.246.55, 13.107.213.55, 2620:1ec:bdf::55, ...
Connecting to update.code.visualstudio.com (update.code.visualstudio.com)|13.107.246.55|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2024-03-08 14:30:18 ERROR 404: Not Found.

ERROR: Failed to download https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:a6606b6ca720bca780c2d3c9d4cc3966ff2eca12/server-linux-x64/stable to /home/adduser/.vscode-server/bin/a6606b6ca720bca780c2d3c9d4cc3966ff2eca12-1709901016.tar.gz
```

I was trying to install Visual Studio Code on my WSL 2, because I was informed by [the Odin Project](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/the-odin-project/) that they don't really support Windows as an operating system. So I installed WSL and Ubuntu, but I can't install Visual Studio Code on my WSL (I have a Visual Studio Code installation on Windows already).

Comment: Hmm - I haven't dived into how the update code works (recently), but just attempting the URL that is in the error (https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:a6606b6ca720bca780c2d3c9d4cc3966ff2eca12/server-linux-x64/stable) in a browser also results in a 404.

Comment: Not sure it's going to help here, but the first troubleshooting step with issues like these is always to simply delete (or rename, if you feel safer) the `~/.vscode` subdirectory. It will be automatically re-generated the next time you run `code`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to confirm that - It's `~/.vscode-server`, as shown in your error message.

Comment: Where exactly can I find this subdirectory?

Comment: @BlakeOnly `~` (tilde) is shell shorthand for the home directory (which you can typically also get from the `$HOME` environment variable). see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables ("tilde expansion")

Comment: My home directory doesn't have that. Is that another word for the root directory in wsl? Is the vscode-server subdirectory on Windows or in my wsl?

Comment: I've uninstalled both wsl and Ubuntu 22.04.3 and reinstalled them but I'm still getting the same error and I don't see this vscode-server subdirectory in my home directory. Is it hidden?

Comment: @BlakeOnly Yes, it is hidden - That's the use of the leading period/dot in a file/directory name in Linux.  You would need `ls -a` to see it.  If you are simply using `ls`, then files/directories that start with a dot will not be displayed.  Try `ls ~ -la` for convenience.

Comment: There's a chance that the installation has never gotten to the step of creating the directory, however, in which case we need to move on to other troubleshooting steps, of course.  My next question would be - Is your VSCode in Windows fully up to date?  I've never had this be a problem (I usually run several months behind before updating), but it's definitely trying to download a file version that doesn't exist.

Comment: On my system, the latest commit that it pulled was `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:019f4d1419fbc8219a181fab7892ebccf7ee29a2/server-linux-x64/stable`, which does exist and can be downloaded via browser.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm just gonna have to reinstall everything I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a web browser, I also tried [the download URL](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:a6606b6ca720bca780c2d3c9d4cc3966ff2eca12/server-linux-x64/stable) that the error message provided on your system and I received a 404 "Not found" on that file.

You aren't the first person to have experienced this particular problem, apparently.  [Issue #9214](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9214) on the `vscode-remote-server` shows the same commit hash failing to download.

The response from a Microsoft Developer for VSCode there was:

> a6606b6ca720bca780c2d3c9d4cc3966ff2eca12 is not the official release build- seems like you might have ended up on a private build somehow? You are also on an out of date version, so updating or uninstall/reinstall should fix it

Uninstall VSCode itself, download the installer from Microsoft directly, and reinstall.

As mentioned in the comments, *if* there's a `~/.vscode-server` in your Linux home directory, then I would delete or rename it as well for good measure.

Comment: Is it possible that the original download came from CSDN.net?  I found the same hash there in a Google search.  A Reddit thread suggested that this might be a less than reputable site.

Comment: Thanks, though I thought I got it from an official site at first. Just to be sure, where is the official site to download vscode and should I get the user or system install?

Comment: @BlakeOnly Official site is (probably the one you are already at, given the "User" vs. "System" question) - [code.visualstudiocode.com/downloads](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) (confirmed through the MS-owned Github repo).  The last time I installed, there wasn't even the option for system-vs-user (I believe it was "System"-only), so I had to look that up.  [Here's the difference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_user-setup-versus-system-setup) - I'd probably opt for User.

Comment: Always possible that there was some sort of goof on the MS side that temporarily put a wrong version up, and you (and the other user on Github) just happened to catch that.

Comment: Reinstalling vscode and deleting the vscode-server directory is what did the trick. Thanks for your help everyone